# How to only perform action once instance created?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

My code:

```py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
  <My_CODE>
  if <having_register>:
    <send_email_to_admin>
```

but this function will work when I run an update instance ( The 'force_insert' and 'force_update' parameters can be used to insist that the "save" must be an SQL insert or update )
so if I just want to send an email to admin only once having a new registration? Any way to check the request method or prevent force_insert in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the value of the pk:

```py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
  <My_CODE>
  if self.pk is None:
    <send_email_to_admin>
```

Otherwise you could send the email in the view after having called `save`.

Comment: thanks, I tried to add a boolean state "is_send_email_to_admin". But I think this doesn't good way, because I had a mass old databse.

Comment: @HuyNguyen I don't think that is a problem, but you can also check if the `pk` is `None` (I've edited my answer). Otherwise put the code to send the email in the signup view, put it after you save the instance / perform the creation with the serializer. You could also use a post_save signal and check the `created` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Another way you can solve this is by using django signals, and use the [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/#post-save) signal and check the `created` parameter. A good example for django signals could be this one [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html), it shows the setup needed for django signals to work.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from yourApp.models import yourModel

@receiver(post_save, sender=yourModel)
def new_instance_created(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
       <send_email_to_admin>
```